# In Django, how to add on_delete constraint on an inherited model

Tags: python, django, django-models, cascade

I have two models in Django:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    ...

class Buick(Car):
    ...
```

Currently I can't delete a `car` with a related `buick` because I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`localdb`.`buick`, CONSTRAINT `car_ptr_id_refs_id_b38c9532` FOREIGN KEY (`car_ptr_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`))')
```

So I'd like to add a cascade delete buicks when I delete a car, but to where? Django's `on_delete` is applied to a ForeignKey. But since the foreignkey isn't exposed, I can't think of a django way to do this, only through mysql.

Comment: In your field: `field = models.F....Key(on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: What you want is the default behavior.

Comment: However, you can add a `OneToOne` relation in `Buick` to `Car`, specifying `parent_link=True` and `on_delete=models.CASCADE`

Comment: and BTW, creating a separate model for each different kind of car will be unmanagable.